# Map<String, Integer> foo - how do I get the value of the integer - JAVA

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a method:

```
  public void updateBoard (Map<String, Integer> foo)
```

How do I find out the value of the Integer? I'm trying foo.get() but it just gives me the key.

Thanks!

Comment: Which `Integer`? A `Map` may contain several.

Comment: why is foo.get(key) not working?? this should return you the value of the specified key... is this the actual code snippet from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all Integer values of the `Map` with:

```
foo.values();
```

Because a `Map` is a `key->value` construct.

With

```
foo.keySet();
```

you get all `key`s.

And with

```
foo.get("key1");
```

you get the appropriate `value` for the `key` `key1`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how map works

```
Map <String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
myMap.put("manikant",123);
// Many more put..
System.out.println(myMap.get("manikant"));
// In case you are using java 8. you can also try this.
myMap.forEach( (k,v) -> System.out.println("Key: " + k + ": Value: " + v));
```

output

```
123
```

in your case you can use `foo.get(/*enter your key*/);`

For more Information [see how map works in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get all the values in the map, use `foo.values()`.

If you are trying to get the value to a specific key in the map, use `foo.get(<key>)`.

Hope it helps!